# Ajax Success data returns complete HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsp

I'm using `iFrame` class JSP page with Date picker field on it. On selecting a date from the picker, I'm sending the date to the Struts Action using jQuery AJAX call like below:

```
$( "#datepickerStart" ).datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText, instance) {//date select from picker to trigger
  $.ajax({
    type: "Post",// post method
    url: 'checkAvailability.do?operation=getlist&datepickerStart='+ ("#datepickerStart").val(), // passing URL with date value to STRUTS Action
    data: "date="+date,
    //dataType: "application/json",
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data); //getting with the complete HTML page
    }
  }); 
 }
});
```

And from DB I'm fetching the results in LIST and converting to JSON object like below:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();// Using google GSON to convert to JSON
String json = new Gson().toJson(lRList);
response.setContentType("application/json");// setting content type
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); //setting character encoder
response.getWriter().write(json);// writing to response the JSON object
System.out.println("JSON Object::"+json);
```

And in standard output gives me the result like this:

```
JSON Object::[{"bookDate":"2014-07-11","fromTime":"2:00PM","totime":"3:30PM","userID":"XXX","isSuccess":false},
{"bookDate":"2014-07-11","fromTime":"10:30AM","totime":"11:00AM","userID":"XXX","isSuccess":false}]
```

But the alert in Ajax success gives the complete HTML page :(. I need this data and want to populate the values in the same JSP by showing in a div table. So can anyone help me on this to resolve it and let me know where I'm doing the mistake...

Comment: did you try to set the datatype as json & what is happening on the server (jsp)?

Comment: If i use data type as JSON I couldnt make an AJAX call itself

Answer (score 0):

i think you should use get instead of post in the ajax call

```
    $( "#datepickerStart" ).datepicker({
      onSelect: function(dateText, instance) {//date select from picker to trigger
      $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: 'checkAvailability.do?operation=getlist&datepickerStart='+         ("#datepickerStart").val(), // passing URL with date value to STRUTS Action
        data: "date="+date,
        //dataType: "application/json",  
        success: function(data) {
          alert(data); //getting with the complete HTML page
        }
      }); 
     }
    });
```

Comment: No improvement :( same HTML content only returning

Comment: did you tried to browse the same URL from your browser, it should return JSON object if everything is correct, if it still return the full page i suggest that you check the JSP page

Answer (score 0):

setup AJAX error to get the error like:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    error: function(jqXHR, e) {
        var msg = '';
        if(jqXHR.status==0){
            msg = 'You are offline!!\n Please Check Your Network.';
        }else if(jqXHR.status==404){
            msg = 'Requested URL not found.';
        }else if(jqXHR.status==500){
            msg = 'Internal Server Error.<br/>'+jqXHR.responseText;
        }else if(e=='parsererror'){
            msg = 'Error: Parsing JSON Request failed.';
        }else if(e=='timeout'){
            msg = 'Request Time out.';
        }else {
            msg = 'Unknow Error.<br/>'+x.responseText;
        }

        console.log('error: '+jqXHR.responseText);
        console.log('Error msg: '+msg);     
    }
});
```

and then set datatype as json in your AJAX call as your getting response in Json format like:

```
$("#datepickerStart").datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText, instance) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: 'checkAvailability.do?operation=getlist&datepickerStart='+$("#datepickerStart").val(),
    data: "date="+date,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  }); 
 }
});
```

also you were forgot to put `$` starting of `("#datepickerStart").val()`

for further reference checkout [my app](https://github.com/abhishek333/ServletAjaxDatePickerPostJson/blob/master/WebContent/js/main.js)